# separate HTML views in MVC

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller

I'm working with MVC (php) for a tiny website. 
For the moment, each view is included from the controller, but just one HTML file per controller.

To begin to optimize (I think), I want to cut some files in two/three parts :

1. header.php (just html headers).
2. Headband : this part is my problem, because if a user is connected, I want to display user informations, if he's not connected, I want to display "Register/Login" links. Am I forced to create two different files for this headband ?  Is it really a good practice ?  it seems not to be a proper way...

If you know some best practices or exemples, thank you.

3. Footer.php, not important.

Comment: why do you specificly want to use only one php webpage file per controller?

Comment: No. now it's like that, but I can change that.  (I didn't create the website base, so that's complicated).  But I don't know if it's a good practice...

Comment: i should advice you just make a plain: header.php and a footer.php(IF they dont ever change) and then import them in the templates in the view folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly no expert when it comes to MVC architecture, but I believe that you should have some logic in your controller to determine whether you need to display the register link or whether you need to display account info. You'd save this in a variable. Then, in your view, depending on the value of the variable you've set, you display one or the other, which can be included as other views themselves.

A bit of pseudocode:

Controller:

```
if (user is logged in) {
display = 'register link'
}
else {
display = 'account info'
}
```

View:

```
print display
```

Comment: more probably in the view you use a foreach loop to check all the navigation parts(which will be stored in the database) plus you will get in the controller the navigations for that specific controller

Comment: @GiovanniLeGrand That's certainly another way to go about it. I guess the main point for the OP here is to ensure that logic is going in the controller, whatever that logic may be (there's always multiple ways to do anything), and only presentation information goes in the view.

Comment: ur absolutely right but foreach loops are very common in views because you can just like in this case send an array of objects containing the navigation objects(links, showable text etc) which you call on

Comment: @GiovanniLeGrand Oh absolutely agreed. You need basic control structures like loops and conditionals in views as well, but the 'business logic' as such should be taken care of in the controllers.

Comment: yeah ment to say that you have to check what navigation items to grab in the models